# UEFI boot and different OVMF firmware files when building a VM

Tags: uefi, kvm-virtualization, qemu

What is the difference between the UEFI/OVMF firmwares available in Ubuntu 22.04? Which should I use when building general purpose Windows and Linux VMs in QEMU/KVM with UEFI & Secure Boot?

1. OVMF_CODE_4m.fd
2. OVMF_CODE_4m.ms.fd
3. OVMF_CODE_4m.secboot.fd
4. OVMF_CODE_4m.snakeoil.fd
5. OVMF_CODE.fd
6. OVMF_CODE.ms.fd
7. OVMF_CODE.secboot.fd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`4M` is the size of the firmware, the other file is 2M. Perhaps some older specifications or older devices had a smaller area for the firmware to reside? If you feel like trawling through historic UEFI Specifications to see if/when a requirement changed (with references) then comment and I'll edit this answer.

The "plain" file with just `CODE` and no suffix is a firmware which allows Secure Boot to be compromised or disabled, such as with `<loader secure='no'>` in your libvirt Domain XML. **If you don't want Secure Boot, use this one.**

`ms` is for firmware with Microsoft's Secure Boot signing keys, and is actually just a symlink to the `secboot` file. [Reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/edk2/+bug/1864535)

`secboot` is firmware which supports Secure Boot (which the plain image does) and which also enforces Secure Boot hardware requirements like SMM (which the plain image doesn't do). **If you want actual secure boot, this is the one you should use.** [Reference](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/edk2/+bug/1864535)

`snakeoil` is pre-signed with a set of Debian private keys which are shipped along with the package, to save you having to recompile from Tianocore's source just to test situations where a private key is needed. Because the private key is public knowledge and on everyone else's system too, **you should never use this on your production VMs.** [Reference](https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/cip-dev/patch/20200629125400.13968-6-Quirin.Gylstorff@siemens.com/)